# WordPress releases requests from all origins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Just of curiosity, does anyone have an explanation because WordPress allows requests from any source to the rest API? Working like a wildcard? It seems strange to me!

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L590

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It's up to the owner of the website whether to allow external requests or not. (And since you may ask, there are plugins to restrict external access to the REST API.)

Comment: @cabrerahector, thanks for the answer. Wouldn't it be more prudent not to release by default and if the developer wants to, use the filters to allow it?

Comment: Let's put it this way: if you're building a website that provides members-only content for example then yes in that case it makes sense that you'll want to restrict access to any public endpoint that exposes private content to non-authenticated users. Otherwise, if your content can already be seen on your website restricting access to the REST API doesn't make a lot of sense. This is probably one of the reasons why the WP devs decided to allow free access to `GET` endpoints and provided filters so devs -like yourself- can later on change this behavior if they wanted to.